# Is there a "cohomology theory" for involutive algebras?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, cohomology, involutions

I'm aware that there are cohomology theories for algebraic structures *related* to involutive algebras (or "involution algebras" or "$*$-algebras" if you prefer those terms) like Lie algebras and groups. In order to create these, it's necessary to construct *rings* out of these non-rings. In the Lie algebra case, one passes to the universal enveloping algebra. In the group case, one passes to the group algebra.

Once one finds a ring whose category of modules is equivalent to the category of the desired representations, one can use the Tor and Ext functors.

**Anyway, is anything remotely like this possible for the class of all finite dimensional involution algebras over some algebraically closed or real-closed field?**

Comment: One can define Ext directly from an abelian category, without introducing a ring, so there is no need for the group algebra or universal enveloping algebra.